# referencing worksheet with vlookup

Tags: vba, excel

New to this, only been doing it around 24 hours. 12 of those hours have been researching this problem. I have found so many pages with examples that seem like they SHOULD work, but haven't. I must be missing sth blatantly obvious.

My code:

1. opens a msgbox, with which the user chooses (types in) an existing worksheet. Currently there is only one worksheet, C1.
2. the macro then uses a vlookup to find a the value in a cell, which is stored in a variable for later use. The cell I'm trying to find contains 2016.1. It is located in Cell C25 of sheet C1.

The problem is the vlookup. I get "runtime error 1004: Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class".

I know my variables *Prodcode* contains the correct sheet name (C1), and *ForecastYear* contains the correct year (2016.1). I think my issue is that I'm not referencing the worksheet name somehow, but I've tried to follow examples from so many websites, and none of them work.

---

```
Function WorksheetExists(WSName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    WorksheetExists = Worksheets(WSName).Name = WSName
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim ProdCode As String
Do Until WorksheetExists(ProdCode)
    ProdCode = InputBox("Enter Product Code: ", "Enter Product Code:", "i.e C1")
    If Not WorksheetExists(ProdCode) Then MsgBox ProdCode & _
        " doesn't exist!", vbExclamation
Loop
Sheets(ProdCode).Select

Me.Title.Caption = "Forecast data for " & ProdCode
Me.Label2012.Caption = Format(Now(), "yyyy")
Me.Label1sta.Caption = "1st Qtr"
Me.Label2nda.Caption = "2nd Qtr"
Me.Label3rda.Caption = "3rd Qtr"
Me.Label4tha.Caption = "4th Qtr"

Me.LabelFc1.Caption = "Forecast"
Me.Labelwfc1.Caption = "Weighted Forecast"
Me.LabelwD1.Caption = "Weighted Demand"

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

'1st quarter current year predictions
Dim ForecastYear As Double
ForecastYear = Year(Now) + .1 'the .1 is to break the year into quarters

MsgBox (ForecastYear)       'for debugging only. checks the correct year is selected
MsgBox (ProdCode)           'for debugging only. checks the correct worksheet is selected

Dim Forecast As Double
Forecast = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ForecastYear, _
    Sheets(ProdCode).Range("A9:J5000"), 10, False)
Forecast = Round(Forecast, 2)

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
With ListBox1
    .AddItem ForecastYear
    .AddItem Forecast
    .AddItem ""

End With

End Sub
```

Sorry, I know this has likely been asked before. I may have even stared at the answer on another page and not realised it was the answer.

Comment: it should be the vlookup cannot find a match of the value it is looking for. you can put a `on error resume next` right before the vlookup line. Then `on error goto 0` after the vlookup line to reset the error. Also you may want to tell vba what to do when `err > 0`, i.e. when error value is not 0.

Comment: I think the answer by @user3598756 will correctly trap your error but, if you think that your data does actually contain `2016.1` and it still is saying it doesn't, be aware that your VLookup is searching for a String of `2016.1` and not the number `2016.1`.  If so, you either need to change the values in your worksheet to be text, or you need to change `ForecastYear` to be a `Double` and calculate it as `Year(Now) + .1`.

Comment: I used the following just in front of my vlookup to check to see if the variables have the correct data. they do. worksheet C1 has 2016.1 in cell C25, and the entire sheet are formatted as numbers.

MsgBox (ForecastYear)       'checks the correct year is selected
MsgBox (ProdCode)           'checks the correct worksheet is selected

I changed to Dim ForecastYear to double and Year(Now) + .1. Still the same error.

Thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to change:

```
Dim Forecast As Double
Forecast = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ForecastYear, Sheets("ProdCode").Range("A9:J5000"), 10, False)
Forecast = Round(Forecast, 2)

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
With ListBox1
    .AddItem ForecastYear
    .AddItem Forecast
    .AddItem ""

End With
```

to:

```
Dim Forecast As Variant
Forecast = Application.VLookup(ForecastYear, Sheets(ProdCode).Range("A9:J5000"), 10, False)
If IsError(Forecast) Then
    MsgBox "couldn't find '" & ForecastYear & "' in Sheets '" & ProdCode & "'"
    Exit Sub    
End If

Forecast = Round(Forecast, 2)     
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
With ListBox1
    .AddItem ForecastYear
    .AddItem Forecast
    .AddItem ""    
End With
```

Furthermore I'd refactor the initial `ProdCode` loop to:

```
ProdCode = Application.InputBox("Enter Product Code: ", "Enter Product Code:", "i.e C1", , , , , 2)
Do While Not WorksheetExists(ProdCode)
    MsgBox ProdCode & " doesn't exist!", vbExclamation
    ProdCode = Application.InputBox("Enter Product Code: ", "Enter Product Code:", "i.e C1", , , , , 2)
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you, this will help when I start coding for user errors. But the current issue is that vlookup cannot find the cell value, even though it exists.

Comment: Did you change your code as per both my snippets? In the first one there's "..Sheets(ProdCode)..." instead of "...Sheets("ProdCode")..." I saw in your code

Comment: Yes, I did change that. Now instead of an error message, this userform shows, but .AddItem Forecast returns a zero, when it should be a decimal number

Comment: Ok, I think I solved it. I read that vlookups need sored data, so I changed it to a lookup function. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: no, it worked when I used the lookup in excel, but when I do the same in the code, it still returns zero. This is infuriating, lol